# If $A^2 = - I$, is $A$ invertible?

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-equations

> If $A^2 = - I$, is $A$ invertible?

My attempt: We know $A^4 = I$. So, $A(A^3) = I$, and thus, the inverse of $A$ is $A^3$. Is that correct?

It is a really basic question but it's a new subject for me.

Comment: If $Ax=0$ then $A^2x=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A(-A) = (-A)A = I$. So the inverse of $A$ is ... .

Comment: is it $-A$... ?

Comment: is my solution wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is, as $-A$ satisfies the definition of the inverse, right?

Comment: If you multiply $A^{2}=-I$ by $A$ you get $A^{3}=-A$. So **both the answers are correct**.

Comment: Your solution is correct, but you threw away some information. Any reflection matrix satisfies your equation but not the original. Note @KaviRamaMurthy's comment.

Comment: I wouldn't really characterize the OPs solution as throwing away information, because it is not relevant that $A^4=I$ could be satisfied by more than just matrices satisfying OPs case

Comment: Why did this answer get downvoted?